# Columna de subquery desconocida

Tags: mysql

¿alguien me pudiera ayudar con esta consulta?

Dice que la columna "TieneNovedadHoy" es desconocida en la clausula
`WHERE`, sin embargo si la quito del `WHERE` y la dejo en el `ORDER BY`,
funciona.

Pero pienso que si la reconoce en la clausula `ORDER BY` la
deberia reconocer en la clausula `WHERE`.

```
SELECT sicor_seguimientos.*, jurisdicciones.nombre AS 
nombre_jurisdiccion, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros 
WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = 
CURDATE()) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS TieneNovedadHoy, (SELECT fecha 
FROM sicor_registros WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = 
sicor_seguimientos.id ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1) As UltimaActualizacion 
FROM sicor_seguimientos INNER JOIN jurisdicciones ON jurisdicciones.id = 
sicor_seguimientos.IdJurisdiccion WHERE TieneNovedadHoy is TRUE AND 
usuario ='anderson' ORDER BY TieneNovedadHoy DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente es así, lo que ocurre es que el `ORDER` es lo último que "procesa" el motor, por lo que en esa instancia el alias de la columna calculada, efectivamente existe, sin embargo al momento de procesar los filtros del `WHERE` dicha columna aún no ha sido resuelta, por lo que te da un error.

`MySql` en particular permite hacer lo siguiente en estos casos:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = CURDATE()) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS TieneNovedadHoy 
      FROM sicor_seguimientos 
      INNER JOIN jurisdicciones 
         ON jurisdicciones.id = sicor_seguimientos.IdJurisdiccion 
      WHERE usuario ='anderson' 
      HAVING TieneNovedadHoy IS TRUE    
      ORDER BY TieneNovedadHoy DESC
```

`HAVING TieneNovedadHoy IS TRUE` en otros dialectos de `SQL` es inválido ya que el `having` solo es válido junto con clausulas `GROUP BY`, pero como te decía, `MySQL` lo permite. La forma más `ANSI SQL` sería:

#### Repetir subconsulta en el `WHERE`

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = CURDATE()) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS TieneNovedadHoy 
      FROM sicor_seguimientos 
      INNER JOIN jurisdicciones 
         ON jurisdicciones.id = sicor_seguimientos.IdJurisdiccion 
      WHERE (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = CURDATE()) THEN TRUE ELSE) is TRUE 
            AND usuario ='anderson' 
      ORDER BY TieneNovedadHoy DESC
```

#### Usar una subconsulta

```
SELECT TieneNovedadHoy
    FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = CURDATE()) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS TieneNovedadHoy 
                FROM sicor_seguimientos 
                INNER JOIN jurisdicciones 
                    ON jurisdicciones.id = sicor_seguimientos.IdJurisdiccion 
                WHERE usuario ='anderson'
        ) T
        WHERE T.TieneNovedadHoy IS TRUE
        ORDER BY T.TieneNovedadHoy DESC
```

#### Resolverlo mediante `LEFT JOIN`

No veo que no se pueda hacerlo también de esta forma:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS TieneNovedadHoy 
      FROM sicor_seguimientos 
      INNER JOIN jurisdicciones 
         ON jurisdicciones.id = sicor_seguimientos.IdJurisdiccion 
      LEFT JOIN sicor_registros
         ON sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id
         AND sicor_registros.fecha = CURDATE() 
      WHERE (CASE WHEN sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) is TRUE 
            AND usuario ='anderson' 
      ORDER BY TieneNovedadHoy DESC
```

Comment: La solucion que había tomado era repetir la consulta en la clausula WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverla.

Los alias de columnas no están permitidos en la clausula WHERE debido a que cuando esta se ejecuta el valor de la columna aun no ha sido determinado.

La solución fue:

SELECT sicor_seguimientos.*, jurisdicciones.nombre AS 
nombre_jurisdiccion, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros 
WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = 
CURDATE()) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS TieneNovedadHoy, (SELECT fecha 
FROM sicor_registros WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = 
sicor_seguimientos.id ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1) As UltimaActualizacion 
FROM sicor_seguimientos INNER JOIN jurisdicciones ON jurisdicciones.id = 
sicor_seguimientos.IdJurisdiccion WHERE (SELECT id FROM sicor_registros 
WHERE sicor_registros.IdSeguimiento = sicor_seguimientos.id AND fecha = 
CURDATE()) is TRUE AND 
usuario ='anderson' ORDER BY TieneNovedadHoy DESC